# ASP.NET / Crystal Report: Crystal Report Viewer Toolbar is Broken

Tags: crystal-reports, toolbar, crystal-reports-2010

I am currently using Crystal Report (for Visual Studio 2010), version 13.0.2
There's a funny error every time I run my web form:

[image]

I tried removing the existing style sheet of my web form, and the viewer's toolbar is showing properly.

Is there a way to resolve this? I still want to use the existing style sheet.

Comment: Looks like security issue with IIS, check if stylesheets are available on read permissions

Comment: I am currently running the web form using Visual Studio 2010. Where exactly do I set the read permissions?

Comment: there exists couple ways to deal with it, have a look at http://forums.iis.net/t/1192074.aspx/1

Comment: @abramlimpin have you solved your problem?

Comment: @JaysonTamayo No, not yet.

Comment: @abramlimpin have you done any workaround for this issue?